# Where to obtain Eurex level 2 historical order book data from?

Tags: market-data, futures, eurex

What are some possible sources to obtain Eurex level 2 historical order book data from?

Unfortunately I have only been able to find 1 source - namely Eurex itself, which charges 2000 Euro/month for the last 3 months and 1500 Euro/month for older months.

That, however, gives you the entire exchange. I was hoping the cherry pick the instruments I needed, e.g. maybe only the 10y bund future and thus get to a more reasonable quote of a few hundred per month?

Answer (score 1):

You can get netted level 2 Eurex data from InteractiveData (derived from CEF Core).

For un-netted data the only place I know of is the Eurex datashop. I've been looking for un-netted data for Bund/Bobl/Schatz without success for a while.